# How do I keep a process open?

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

I have a web application in ASP.Net/C# (using MVS), and I want to be able to launch some programs on the client side (this should be safe since it's only for intranet use), and keep these programs open in order to give them some command inputs through the web app.

For example, I would like to open "cmd.exe" client-side, and then being able to send multiple commands one after another (synchronized with some buttons of my web form) to the process.

How can I do this? I've read a lot about using a block of Javascript with an ActiveX object, or in C# with `System.Diagnostics.Process`, but I'm quite stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that there is nothing "safe" when trying to run arbitrary command under user's credentials... What you are trying to achieve (communicate with arbitrary application, or at least standalone CMD) is relatively hard even with just client C# application, much harder with web page even with IE on full trust site. There are likely much better ways to achieve what you are actually after (unless you are writing virus of sorts). I'd recommend getting starting with normal C# application doing what you want and than see if you want to somehow convert it into web page.

Comment: Indead, i tried to create my app in Java first. But the interface managing is time consuming and i have the same problem with threading the process in order to keep one open in order to send input commands to the program

Comment: I think your idea that communicating with existing local process would be easier using sandbox JavaScript in browser compared to locally running Java is somewhat flawed. Good luck. Side note: it looks like you are trying to reinvent telnet, remote PowerShell or some other remote shell tool/protocol... Consider specifying your actual goal in the question so better options could be offered as answers.

Comment: Thanks... i will start from ground again... asp.net may not have been the wiser choice to do what i want.
May i ask you what you would have used to makt this the easiest way (in fact it is somewhat jobrelated to you since i want to make a script with an interface to easily deploy games on a Microsoft Console ^^)

Comment: Start with writing local program that does what you need - communication between your local program and page in browser is way more achievable (start another copy that will post commands, or even local web server with CORS support to allow non-full trust pages to use your tool). If you want to see if there is anything specific for your case - post on dev support forum you should have access to.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function RunEXE()
 {
     var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
     var prog = "c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe";
     oShell.Run('"'+prog+'"',1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at custom protocol handlers, that's what e.g. Steam uses. You'd simply have a link like `myprotocol://dosomething/whatever` and it will launch your client-side application with the given URL.

It's basically just about writing a registry key: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For example, to register a protocol named `alert`, you can do this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

This will cause the application in `command` to be launched when you navigate to an url that starts with `alert://`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but i already knew this.
My problem is that the program i want to launch open a "shell like" interface (with a specific environment).

So as soon as i do my process.start(...), the program exit (without any error).

I would like to keep it running in order to put a set of commands in the input stream.

Comment: @Raizyl But you can do that, that just depends on the client application you launch. If you don't want it to exit, then don't make it exit, just let it wait for more instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Using c#

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
startInfo.Arguments = "list of args";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Now after that you can keep checking weather the is open or not by

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
```

or

```
Process[] chromes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
```

Check if you process is open or not then pass args to it

Comment: This would only launch the process on the server-side. The OP wants to run a process on the client.

Comment: Ok answer, but to some other question...